# What does the word "lurn" mean?

Tags: vocabulary, internet

Is the word "lurn" in the phrase "It's time to lurn together" just an intentional misspelling of "learn" or does it have another meaning here?

http://beckyandjoes.com/kickstarter/

[image: T-Shirt with phrase 'It's time to lurn together']

Comment: It's meant to be taken as humorously ironic, a misspelling of "learn".

Comment: I see. So no double/other meaning here?

Comment: I don't think so. It's like a T-shirt with the words *I'm with stoopid →* on the front.

Comment: related: [What's it called when words are deliberately misspelled but pronunciation remains unchanged?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46101/what-is-it-called-when-words-are-deliberately-spelled-incorrectly-but-pronunciat)

Comment: we gon' lurn y'all good here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Learn" is this context is intentionally misspelled to add humor to the context. It shows that they have much left to learn since they misspelled the word "learn" itself.

Answer (score -1):

> Most people familiar with the language would recognise that **lurn**
>   is not an English word.
>
> ```
>                      It's time to lurn together...
> ```
>
> ***..in one-word, it's being*** [image].
>
> Incidentally, if you [google "lurn](https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en-IN&source=hp&q=lurn%20meaning&gbv=2&oq=Lurn%20mean&gs_l=heirloom-hp.3.0.35i39j0i10l9.920.2589.0.3993.5.5.0.0.0.0.671.1498.2-2j1j0j1.4.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-hp..1.4.1498.eijPLKpXis0)", you get a result similar to
>   "learn.

Answer (score -2):

I think "lurn" is an intentional misspelling of "learn".

Comment: It isn't slang, just an intentional misspelling, as you say.

Comment: Lets call it "Internet slang" then :).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_slang

Comment: Link us to an example of "lurn" as "internet slang", please. If you'll do that I can upvote.

Comment: @LittleEva, i can't, but http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/internet-slang explicitly lists "intentional misspellings". And we see examples all the time, with famous misspellings like "Teh", "Can i haz sum cheezburgers" or "dat gurl". I think "lurn" for "learn" is excactly in this category.

Comment: You may be correct, then again, "lurn" may be more "T-shirt" slang then internet slang.

Comment: Hmm. .Maybe.. But it does look like it would fit perfectly in the "I haz lurned to make cheezburgerz" sentence.. Then again, who says "t-shirt" slang isn't just Internet slang on a t-shirt.  Well. anyway, it is not that important to the answering of the original question, so ill rephrase it again.

Comment: I'm trying to help your answer out, here. Sure, it "*would fit*" But is it established fact? Or is it supposition? Back up the assertion or you have only the assertion. :-)

Comment: @LittleEva I'm not in opposition. There is no proof to offer, safe for writing to the author of the t-shirt and asking. And even then, will there be room for ambiguity. Yet the misspelling is most likely intentional, yet unprovable, and it follows the semantics of internet slang, but is not proven to be internet slang. So how to convey this, without making false assertions? Maybe i cant. Should i just write "lurn may be an intentional misspelling of learn, for humorous purposes" and leave out everything else?

Comment: If its "my opinion" without citation to authority then I will usually admit that by saying, IMO or something to that effect. My encouragement to cite support is because your answer stands a better chance of garnering positive upvotes when it is a supported assertion.